# Matplotlib image to show on Flask app hosted in Heroku

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, heroku

I am trying to make a Flask app and hosting it on Heroku.

The app takes some text and numeric data, performs calculations and shows a graph when the "Generate" button is clicked. It stores the Matplotlib generated plots on a folder called '/static'.
Now, on Heroku, having a folder name called '/static' is not allowed and doesn't work. But after reading at a few places, i tried using '/tmp', and that too doesn't work.

Below image is what I get.

[image: Matplotlib plot not showing]

Here is the code that handles the file generation:

```
    if not os.path.isdir('tmp'):
        os.mkdir('tmp')
    else:
        # Remove old plot files
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('tmp', '*.png')):
            os.remove(filename)
    # Use time since Jan 1, 1970 in filename in order make
    # a unique filename that the browser has not chached
    plotfile = os.path.join('tmp', 'matgenimage'+'.png')
    plt.savefig(plotfile)
    return plotfile
```

The code for the full Flask app is here:

https://github.com/cae-live/cae-sandbox/

Comment: Check and try implementing this:                                                                   <br/>                     https://towardsdatascience.com/python-plotting-api-expose-your-scientific-python-plots-through-a-flask-api-31ec7555c4a8                                                                   
  <br/> https://python-sci-plotting.herokuapp.com/ <br/> https://gitlab.com/dice89/python-plotting-api

Answer (score 0):

Done!

[image]

This video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgSFm3wM6g4
and this repository -> https://github.com/marquitobb/flask_graficas 
made it totally clear to me. need to pass the image in the same request using BytesIO and base64.

Comment: How to use the same functionality to serve a csv file?